# How could I translate this reference

Tags: mysql

I wrong to put some reference in my MySql tables. I think an example will show to you my problem (I really hope so). These are an example of the structure of my tables :

```
tableMain
id (int)
trackid(varchar)
data(text)

tableArtist
idArtist(int)
ref(varchar)
artist(varchar)

tableEvent
idEvent(int)
ref(varchar)
event(varchar)
```

These are the datas :

```
tableMain
1       abc    primo
2       def    secondo
3       ghi    terzo

tableArtist
1       abc    artist2
2       abc    artist4
3       ghi    artist5
4       def    artist1
5       ghi    artist3

tableEvent
1       def    event1
2       abc    event5    
3       222    event3
4       ghi    event2
5       abc    event4
```

I'd like to change the values of ref on both tableEvent and tableArtist replacing with the value of the corespondent id frome the tableMain :

```
tableMain
1       abc     primo
2       def     secondo
3       ghi     terzo

tableArtist
1       1     artist2
2       1     artist4
3       2     artist5
4       2     artist1
5       3     artist3

tableEvent
1       2     event1
2       1     event5    
3       2     event3
4       3     event2
5       1     event4
```

Is it possible on MySql or I need a sort of script (such as PHP) to done it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableArtist, tableMain
    SET tableArtist.ref = tableMain.id
    WHERE tableArtist.ref = tableMain.trackid

UPDATE tableEvent, tableMain
    SET tableEvent.ref = tableMain.id
    WHERE tableEvent.ref = tableMain.trackid
```

**EDIT**: To address @colinmarc's concern, after updating the data you could:

```
ALTER TABLE tableArtist MODIFY ref INT;
ALTER TABLE tableEvent MODIFY ref INT;
```

Comment: @colinmarc: The datatype could certainly be modified afterwards if desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a few queries, yes. Using your naming convention:

```
ALTER TABLE tableArtist ADD COLUMN idMain int;
UPDATE tableArtist SET idMain = (
    SELECT id FROM tableMain where tableArtist.ref = tableMain.trackid
);
```

Then, once you know the data is good:

```
ALTER TABLE tableArtist DROP COLUMN ref;
```

Comment: You're potentially looking at refactoring a lot of code by introducing a completely different column name here.

Comment: that's a good point. you could always change the name after - but I didn't realize you could change the type of a column after it's filled, so that would work too.